# How to check if queried data does not contain any record

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have code as follows:

```
 $order = $this->getTableGateway('order');

        $select = new Select();

        if($txtFromOrderDate!="" && $txtToOrderDate=="")
        {
        $select->from('order')
            ->join('user', 'order.user_id = user.id', array('email'))
            ->where ("order.created between ".$txtFromOrderDate." and (
                        SELECT MAX(  `created` ) 
                        FROM  `order`
                        )"
                     );
        }

        else if($txtFromOrderDate=="" && $txtToOrderDate!="")
        {
         $select->from('order')
            ->join('user', 'order.user_id = user.id', array('email'))
            ->where ("order.created between  (
                        SELECT MIN(  `created` ) 
                        FROM  `order`
                        ) and ".$txtToOrderDate
                     );
        }


        else if($txtFromOrderDate!="" && $txtToOrderDate!="")
        {
        $select->from('order')
            ->join('user', 'order.user_id = user.id', array('email'))
            ->where ("order.created between ".$txtFromOrderDate." and ".$txtToOrderDate);
             //->where ('order.created between '.$txtFromOrderDate.'  and '.$txtToOrderDate);
        }

        else if($txtFromOrderDate=="" && $txtToOrderDate=="")
        {
        $select->from('order')
            ->join('user', 'order.user_id = user.id', array('email'));

        }   

        $data = $order->selectWith($select)->toArray();
```

As we can see depending on different conditions in if select statement is changing.

at last I am executing it through:

```
$data = $order->selectWith($select)->toArray();
```

i want to check if query has returned any record in $data or not.

How to check if query has returned 0 records????

Please help me.

I am using MySQL server and Zend Framework for PHP

Comment: you can count the size or length of `$data`.

Comment: @sgt means by this way : sizeof($data) .... will it be 0 if no records present???

Comment: @ÁngelDiMaría When will we see you scoring again? Your last goal was 40 days ago!

Comment: @php-dev trying hard to get in form again! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$data` will be an `array`. if no records are present then

`count($data)` will return `0`

Answer (score 3):

use sizeof($data) or count($data)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!empty($data)) {
   //query has returned 1 or more results
}
else {
   //query has returned 0 result
}
```